# How to use these two class decorators together with functools.update_wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, functools

I was reading about decorators and tried to mix these two examples and make them class decorators instead of regular functions. The first one only lets you run a function once per argument and the second one counts how many times you've run that function. They both work fine separated but when I try to decorate a simple function with both at the same time it fails... Or doesn't really fail but prints an unexpected wrong result. I did some reading and found that the functools module can help but I'm not sure how.

```
from functools import update_wrapper

class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.memo = dict()
        update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.func(args)
        else:
            print("cls decorator. You have printed this before")
        return self.memo[args]


class CallCounter:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.calls = 0
        self.__name__ = func.__name__
        update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calls += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)


@Memoize
@CallCounter
def doubleprint(x):
    for elem in x:
        print(elem + " " + elem)


doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Bye')

print(doubleprint.calls)

doubleprint('Hello')

doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Hello')
doubleprint('Bye')

print(doubleprint.calls)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `update_wrapper` updates the `__dict__` from a wrapped class. So your `func` in `Memoize` is being overwritten with the `func` in `CallCounter` which means `Memoize` is directly calling your `doubleprint()` function and never calling `CallCounter`.

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        print(type(self.func))  # <class '__main__.CallCounter'>
        self.memo = dict()
        update_wrapper(self, func)
        print(type(self.func))  # <class 'function'>
```

You can fix this by doing:

```
        update_wrapper(self, func, updated=[])
```

Which will not copy the `__dict__` from the `CallCounter` into the `Memoize` instance but will still copy `__name__, __doc__`, etc.

To access `CallCounter` class you would:

```
print(doubleprint.__wrapped__.calls)
```

But you need the fix above or this will always print `0` (because it is never called).